# iOS Contacts Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, contacts-framework

So i was doing a tutorial from Sinch! on how to Fetch and Call Contacts,
Well it loads up the Contacts just fine.
The problem is that whenever I select a Contact to call, the app crashes and Xcode shows this error on the console.
Can anyone help me with that?

```
    inchAppToPhoneTutorial[1143:42160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Parameter 'applicationKey' is invalid (was '')'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a70634b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a08821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x0000000108cca77b SINCallOrderByStartTimeComparator + 66724
    3   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x0000000108cb1c6b _ZN6rebrtc13OfflineInvite6encodeERKS0_PhmPm + 4418449
    4   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x0000000108cc4d45 SINCallOrderByStartTimeComparator + 43630
    5   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x0000000108cc496c SINCallOrderByStartTimeComparator + 42645
    6   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x00000001088268e9 -[DetailViewController initSinchClient] + 89
    7   SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x0000000108825e8a -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad] + 234
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010accb06d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010acd14d6 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010acfc393 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1290
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ad0d008 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 697
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ad0e19b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010af051b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010abee344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e03bcdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e02f7a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e02f61e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010dfbd62c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010dfea713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010ab54878 _afterCACommitHandler + 346
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6aae17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6aad87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a68fb9e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a68f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e959a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010ab29f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  SinchAppToPhoneTutorial             0x00000001088257bf main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c4fe68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: whats your iOS version ?

Comment: Im using Xcode 8, but the iOS Deployment Target is 8.3, the code is in Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says what happened at the very top

```
inchAppToPhoneTutorial[1143:42160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Parameter 'applicationKey' is invalid (was '')'
```

So figure out where you're calling something that utilizes an `applicationKey` and figure out why it's blank :)